# React can't setState: setResult always stays undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is the code of the component that cannot setState. There are two states here: cityInput and result. They are declared in the parent component here:

```
export default function App() {
  const [cityInput, setCityInput] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState();

  let pageComponent;
  if (query.page === "News") {
    pageComponent = <News newsCityInput={cityInput} newsResult={result} />;
  } else {
    pageComponent = <Lobby cityInput={cityInput} setCityInput={setCityInput} result={result} setResult={setResult} />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        ...
      </Head>
      {pageComponent}
   </div>
```

Here is the Lobby component that cannot set the state:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Link from 'next/link';
import styles from "./index.module.css";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { responseParser } from "./api/responseParser";

export const Lobby = (props) => {
  const { cityInput, setCityInput, result, setResult } = props;
  const router = useRouter();

  const onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch("/api/generateCity", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ city: cityInput }),
      });

      const data = await response.json();
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        throw data.error || new Error(`Request failed with status ${response.status}`);
      }
      console.log("data26:", data); //data is there
      console.log("parsed data27:", responseParser(data.result)); //data is correctly parsed

      setResult(responseParser(data.result)); // this line doesn't work
      console.log("result30:", result); //result is still undefined


      setTimeout(() => {  //this is an attempt at delaying setResult so that it eventually gets set or to find out if a later console.log is different
        // setResult(responseParser(data.result)); //this doesn't work
        console.log("result35:", result);
        router.push('/News'); //checking if staying on the page for longer fixes the problem
      }, 2000);

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      alert(error.message);
    }
  }

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <img src="/dog.png" className={styles.icon} />
      <h3>Enter a City</h3>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="city"
          placeholder="Enter a city"
          value={cityInput}
          onChange={(e) => setCityInput(e.target.value)}
        />
        {/* <Link href="/News"> */}
        <button type="submit">Generate</button>
        {/* </Link> */}
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};
```

I was expecting to be able to set a state to an array of objects. Instead it remains undefined. I'd be happy if I could set state to literally anything.

1. I've tried compressing the application and putting the Lobby.jsx component inside index.js so that result and setResult are not passed as props.
2. I've added significant setTimeouts to ensure there are no issues with asynchronous code. There is one here to stay on the page before leaving and one at the News component to let the page load.
3. I've tried putting mock data and unparsed data into setResult to see if it could be set incorrectly but it remains undefined.
4. I've put the setResult in the setTimeout and also outside the try block, no luck.
5. I've replaced all of the useState calls with useContext but the same issue persists. I'm happy to provide this code if anyone wants.
6. I've put the call of onSubmit as a callback: <form onSubmit={() => onSubmit}>

Why does my setState function not work?

Comment: What is `query` defined as? That isn't in your code.

Comment: Logging directly after a `setState` call will never show the updated value (`console.log("result30:", result);`), the new value won't be available until the next render cycle. This can't be awaited or seen after a timeout. You can log in the main body of the component or in a `useEffect` which will run on the next render cycle and show the updated state. see: [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: the line underneath it logs to the console: console.log("result35:", result); and it displays undefined as well. 2000ms should be enough time no?

Comment: @Aaron:  
import { useRouter } from "next/router";  
  
import everything else...  

export default function App() {  
  //...  

  const router = useRouter();  
  const { query } = router;   
  
it was just removed for simplicity   
  
ok, formatting goes away. It is nextJS's way of querying the current url. This is a workaround to using something like browserrouter, routes and links that you might see in a regular react app.

Comment: @rarecarrots As I mentioned, no amount of time is enough, it just won't be available until the next render cycle. Simply put a console.log directly under the state declaration in your App component.